Hash function used by knuth on TeX program after scan process
I am studying some TeX program parts finding a lot of materials on line. I understand that "cur_cs" variable, contains the hash function value to identify the control sequence typed after the scan process (not completely).
My difficult is to find into the book where is the "hash function" used by Knuth to calculate the value above. Does DEK use different "hash functions" depending on the specific involved task or do we find only an hash function method used for all issues within the program?
Thank you to all for help & assistance

All control words share the same hash function, the lookup is in texdoc tex §259, is that what you're looking for?

Yes it is. It seems that the variable "h" contains the calculated value with hash function. I search on web and I discovered that Knuth suggested an hash function for ascii character, based on XOR. As a consequence I supposed that this method was used in TeX program so I try to research the XOR function part within it.

LuaTeX uses the default Lua hashing algorithm for table keys, although I'm pretty sure that that's not what you meant.

The source of TeX-the-Program, tex.web is available on CTAN, you can find the documented has function around line 5575 :
@ The value of |hash_prime| should be roughly 85\pct! of |hash_size|, and it
should be a prime number.  The theory of hashing tells us to expect fewer
than two table probes, on the average, when the search is successful.
[See J.~S. Vitter, {\sl Journal of the ACM\/ \bf30} (1983), 231--258.]
@^Vitter, Jeffrey Scott@>

@<Compute the hash code |h|@>=
h:=buffer[j];
for k:=j+1 to j+l-1 do
  begin h:=h+h+buffer[k];
  while h>=hash_prime do h:=h-hash_prime;
  end


The hash function usage appears in §259 of texdoc tex (which basically is TeX-the-Programm). There we find the following code:
function id lookup(j, l : integer ): pointer; { search the hash table }
  label found; { go here if you found it }
  var h: integer; { hash code }
    d: integer; { number of characters in incomplete current string }
    p: pointer; { index in hash array }
    k: pointer; { index in buffer array }
  begin ⟨Compute the hash code h 261⟩;
  p ← h + hash base; { we start searching here; note that 0 ≤h < hash prime }
  loop begin if text(p) > 0 then
      if length(text(p)) = l then
    if str eq buf (text(p), j) then goto found;
    if next(p) = 0 then
      begin if no new control sequence then p ← undefined control sequence
      else ⟨Insert a new control sequence after p, then make p point to it 260⟩;
      goto found;
      end;
    p ← next(p);
    end;
found: id lookup ← p;
  end;

The actual hash function is in §261:
  h ← buffer [j];
  for k ← j + 1 to j + l − 1 do
    begin h ← h + h + buffer [k];
    while h ≥ hash prime do h ← h − hash prime;
    end


Thank you for your answer. Also for me the hash function used to made the hash table can be assumed like this. So the buffer contains the ASCII code of the characters typed. The only particular thing is the double 'h' into the calculation 'hash formula' (h+h..and so on and so on)..


do we find only [one] hash function method used for all issues within the program?

Below are all things related to hash tables in the TeX program, while I still understand them. :)

There are in fact multiple hash tables in TeX, but the primary one (and the one the question mostly asks about) is the one used for multi-letter control sequences, including primitives and user-defined control sequences. (Not including single-character control sequences like \c, or active characters like ~.)
This hash table is, in the Pascal program, an array called hash (§256) of two_halves (§113), i.e. each element of the array has two at-least-16-bit fields, where the right half (hash[p].rh aka text(p)) stores the string number (index in str_start, saying where the string is in the str_pool), and the left half (hash[p].lh aka next(p)) is like pointers for the linked list. (Note that this hash table is used only to give unique identifiers to control sequences. The meanings or values corresponding to the control sequences are stored elsewhere, such as in eqtb.)
This hash table is used whenever control sequences are encountered or being defined, such as with \csname.

The basic idea of a hash table (in general) is that you use an array of size M (say), and given an input K (integer or string or whatever), you hash it to an integer h(K) in range [0…p) where p ≤ M, and then use the position h(K) in the array. The two main decisions to make with any hash table are:

what function h(K) to use, and

how to handle collisions, i.e. what to do when the position h(K) has already been “occupied” in the array for some other K.



For (1), the hash function does not matter too much. As Knuth says in TAOCP (6.4, pages 519–520 of Vol 3):

A good hash function should satisfy two requirements:
a) Its computation should be very fast.
b) It should minimize collisions.
Property (a) is machine-dependent, and property (b) is data-dependent. […]
It is often convenient to use the constant hash function h(K) = 0 when debugging a program, since all keys will be stored together; an efficient h(K) can be substituted later.

Here, the input to be hashed (§259) is the "string of length l > 1 appearing in buffer[j .. (j + l − 1)]", where buffer is an array (§30) of 8-bit integers (ASCII_code = 0..255; §18). The simplest hash function would have been to simply add the bytes together (as buf[j] + buf[j+1] + ... + buf[j+l-1] mod hash_prime). The problem with this hash function would be that permuting the letters results in the same hash function, e.g. "word" and "wodr" would have the same hash. So a small change, that is almost as fast to compute, but avoids this problem, is to do the "h + h" that he does in §261.
Another way of looking at this is: a straightforward hash function would be to treat the input as a single number in binary and take this number mod hash_prime. This would mean multiplying by 256 after each byte is read; instead the above hash function simply multiplies by 2. This is fine as modulo hash_prime whether you use 2 or 256 should not matter much; both are relatively prime to it. (Some Pascal compilers weren't great and "h + h" could well have been faster than "h * 256".)

For (2), the collision-resolution algorithm used for this hash table is one called “coalesced chaining” (or “coalesced hashing”). Here, it means that every element of the hash array contains (apart from the text value) a next pointer (index of another element in the array), and when inserting an element K, we do:

compute p = h(K)
if the array at position p is unoccupied, just insert it there,
otherwise let hash_used be the last unoccupied index in the array, and insert it there (and set the next pointer at position p to point to hash_used).

Similarly when looking up an element, we follow the next pointers. This is what the TeX program does with its id_lookup function (§259), using the global variable no_new_control_sequence to control whether it is a lookup or insertion.

There is another different (entirely unrelated and independent) hash table used in TeX, for maintaining the list of hyphenation exception patterns (called hyph_list, §925). This uses a different method for resolving collisions, namely "open addressing", specifically it's an "ordered hash table" i.e. if the position h is occupied then it's enough to look at positions h, h-1, … which are guaranteed to be in order if part of the same cluster. The hash function it uses (§930) is similar though:
h ← hc[1];
for j ← 2 to hn do h ← (h + h + hc[j]) mod hyph_size;


There is yet another hash table called trie_op_hash (§943). This uses an unusual hash function
h ← abs (n + 313*d + 361*v + 1009*cur_lang) mod (trie_op_size + trie_op_size) − trie_op_size;

(giving a value in range [-trie_op_size .. trie_op_size), which are the bounds of this array). Collision resolution is done simply by linear probing, i.e. trying h, h-1, h-2, etc until an empty slot is found.
If I understand correctly, this hash table only needs insertions (and all its entries are scanned once at the end), i.e. it does not need lookup after building it.

Yet another hash table also used in the hyphenation part of the program is trie_hash (§946), very similar to trie_op_hash, which uses the hash function:
h ← abs(trie_c[p] + 1009*trie_o[p] + 2718*trie_l[p] + 3142*trie_r[p]) mod trie_size;

(clearly basically arbitrary numbers; based on e and pi) and linear probing. (The hash table itself is straightforward but there's some associated tricky code for compressing the trie by “packing” it.)

The first-mentioned hash table (for control sequences) is the only one that is needed after the initial hyphenation patterns have been loaded, so there is some code for dumping and undumping it, to/from a format (.fmt) file. (The others are only needed while building up the hyphenation patterns; there is common code for dumping and undumping the hyphenation patterns, not the hash tables themselves.)
These are all the hash tables used in TeX / all the occurrences of “hash” in the program.
